# Change timeout period of Elastic beanstalk worker daemon on deploy

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk worker ENV but on update or a task that requires it to stop processing it stops after 30s.  I know the Daemon receives a SIGTERM on when to stop, but the time out is only 30s, how do I change this?

I have tried to find anything on this but can't, any help would be great, thanks.